# php convert special character '&' to single character

Tags: php, special-characters

I have a string containing character `&`

And i have got the same string from `$_POST` containing `&`. when i var_dump it, the string form post shows 4 more characters then the `var_dump(_same_string_)`.

I want to treat special characters from "post" as a "single character". What should I do?

I tried:

```
$postString = (string)$postString;
```

tried:

```
vardump(htmlspecialchars($postString));
```

it shows `&` as `&amp` while in `var_dump(_same_string_)` `&` remains same.

Comment: Have you tried `htmlspecialchars_decode()`?

Comment: View the source and you will see the entity. The browser renders the entity as the symbol.

Comment: @frz3993 i never know about it. I searched alot but didn't know what to search exactly. thanks it worked :D post it as answer, i will mark it. thnx :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from html entities back to the characters. Like from `&amp` to `&`, and `&gt` to `>`. Use `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

To do it the other way around, like `&` to `&amp`, use `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) in order to decode the [html entity](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) `&amp;`

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode("&amp;"):
//&
```

---

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/GYzzud)

---

```
htmlspecialchars_decode()
```

> **Convert special HTML entities back to characters**. This function is the
>   opposite of htmlspecialchars(). It converts special HTML entities back
>   to characters. The converted entities are: &, " (when
>   ENT_NOQUOTES is not set), ' (when ENT_QUOTES is set), < and
>   >.